# Executing MySqlCommand (StoredProcedure) with output parameter

Tags: c#, mysql, connector-net

I can't figure out how to use MySQLCommand provided by Connector/NET 3.6.5.  Basically here is the code I'm using and exception I get when I run ExecuteNonQuery. What am I doing wrong here? I have no ideas left :(

```
var connection = GetConnection();
connection.Open();

var command = new MySqlCommand("PredictPaperRankInInterval", connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("p_journalId", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = "test" });
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("p_publishDate", SqlDbType.DateTime) { Value = paper.PublishDate });
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("p_intervalInDays", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = 7 });
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("p_viewsCount", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = paper.ViewsCount });
var rank = new MySqlParameter("p_rank", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
command.Parameters.Add(rank);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

*Exception*

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

*DDL*

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `PredictPaperRankInInterval`(IN p_journalId VARCHAR(32), 
                                              IN p_publishDate DATETIME, 
                                              IN p_intervalInDays INT, 
                                              IN p_viewsCount INT, 
                                              OUT p_rank INT)
```

Comment: can you post the signature of the called stored procedure

Comment: make sure that the parameter types are mapped correctly to the types used in the stored procedure.

Comment: :D So great to have somebody smart around. Had to use MySqlDbType instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
 MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("PredictPaperRankInInterval", con);
 command .CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```